# Is there a community guide or FAQ for comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, guidelines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I had a comment edited, and an apology to the moderator who I assume made the edit removed this afternoon. I assume that I crossed some kind of line with the original, and the apology removed as off topic, but I don't really know for sure.

I've read FAQs on posting questions, but have never seen one for comments, so I was wondering if there was a guide or FAQ to for comments that I could read so I would would be able to avoid this in the future.

Edit - To be clear, I am not disagreeing with the moderation in any way, I simply want to be more clear on the ground rules to participate in the community.

Comment: Comments should generally be topical, and of course courteous. Accept-rate badgering comments are terminated with extreme prejudice. Other comments may be considered obsolete after a brief period. What type of comment did you have removed or edited?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I gently chastised a new user for bringing requirements that should have been in the question later in a response to an answer.  I didn't think I was over the line at the time, which prompted me to ask this question here on meta.

Comment: So for context, it was your comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9470057/414076)?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Yes sir.

Comment: I think you're looking for [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work), which is an official `[faq]` entry. You may also want to read the other posts that come up when you [search for `[faq]` comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+comments).

Answer (score 4):

Comments are generally supposed to be temporary; one of the options when flagging a comment is  "obsolete". Most likely the mod saw your apology comment, at which point the comment was no longer necessary, so he just deleted it. I can't see your [original comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469957/data-structure-in-c-sharp-for-emulate-a-python-tuple-of-tuples/9470057#comment11984119_9470057), so I don't know what you said that warranted editing, but I wouldn't really worry about it; it couldn't have been too bad or the mod would've said something. There isn't any special guide to etiquette in comments, although there is one for posting in general in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)

Answer (score 3):

In general, comments are used to **clarify a post.**  They have no other "official" function.

It is rare, but if I encounter a comment that makes a valid point of clarification but is borderline rude, rather than delete the comment, I will just remove the offending words.